# «Займёт не больше минуты» или «не займёт больше минуты»

Tags: порядок-слов

Вопрос возник по следам [другого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8820/176217), заданного на Мета.руСО. Какой вариант:

- займёт не больше минуты
- не займёт больше минуты

лучше (правильнее) использовать и есть ли вообще разница?

Comment: Чайник долго остывает или чайник долго не остывает? Вечная тема...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Займёт не больше минуты* = займёт *мало*.

*Не займёт больше минуты* = не займёт *много*.

Выражают, по сути, одно и то же, но воспринимаются (невольно) по-разному.

Всё зависит от положения отрицательной частицы НЕ.

*Не больше минуты*- отрицание перед *больше* воспринимается как *мало* , *не займёт больше* - отрицается действие *займёт*, а *больше* воспринимается как *много*.

А так как фраза намекает на дефицит времени, то первый вариант с "мало" предпочтительнее и потому, вероятно, популярнее.

Comment: А если рассмотреть "займёт мало" как **обязательство** в сравнении с "не займёт много" как **опциональность**, только второй вариант можно считать более щадящим с точки зрения экономии времени.

Comment: Спасибо вам за слово "опциональность"!

Comment: пожалуйста. А у вас такого слова раньше не было? :)

Comment: А зачем оно здесь?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я не только никогда не употребляла, но и никогда не видела этого слова в текстах. Видимо, не те тексты читала).

Answer (score 4):

Первый вариант *естественен* для любого контекста (сообщается, что требуемое время незначительно, не больше такой-то величины).

Во втором варианте грамматической ошибки нет, но он звучит напряжённо - как *возражение*  (в этом смысле не совсем вежливо) или как излишне буквальный перевод с английского. Через глагол отрицается законченное суждение "*это займёт больше минуты*", как будто говорящий подразумевает ход мыслей собеседника (как вы полагаете или могли бы подумать); для этого как минимум нужен подходящий контекст.